# Resque error- wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, redis, resque

I am using rescue to handle all the heavy lifting background tasks, 
In my library/parsers/file.rb I have

```
Resque.enqueue(Hello)
```

This will redirect app/workers/file.rb where I have

```
class Hello
def self.perform(page)
.......
.......
end
rescue Exception => e
log "error: #{e}"
end
end
```

my lib/tasks/resque.rake file is

```
    require "resque/tasks"  

task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

I am able to queue the jobs buts when i try to execute the job using

```
    rake resque:work QUEUE=*
```

it is throwing an error by saying

```
    argument error
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

what am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: I've never used resque so I may be wrong, but don't you need to pass a value for the 'page' parameter in to the `Resque.enqueue` call? `Resque.enqueue(Hello, page_value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pjumble  is exactly right, you're not passing the page.

```
Resque.enqueue(Hello, page_id)
```

enqueue takes the Job followed by the args which go into the perform action. If you had:

```
class Hello
 def self.perform(page_number, page_foo, page_bar)
   ...
 end
end
```

Then you would do this:

```
Resque.enqueue(Hello, page_number, page_foo, page_bar)
```